# Address of master PostgreSQL for replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave-replication

What is the address (that goes to pg_hba.conf) for the master computer which is connected only to the internet which a slave VPS server will connect to for PostgreSQL replication?

Comment: It's the IP address of that master server. Only **you** can now that

Answer (score 0):

The address of the master goes into recovery.conf of the replica, not into pg_hba.conf.

On the master, pg_hba.conf needs to have an entry matching the address (and replication user) of the replica so that it can connect to the master to initiate replication.

Answer (score 0):

On Master, pg_hba.conf IP address of slave machine will come.

On slave , recovery.conf file IP address of master will come.

Make sure both slave and master can ping each other .